# What's wrong with this proof that cancellability holds for direct sums of subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U_1, U_2, W$ be subspaces of $V$, where $V$ is some vector space. Incorrect theorem:

If $V = U_1 \oplus W$ and $V = U_2 \oplus W$ then $U_1 = U_2$.

Incorrect proof of the above:

Case 1: Show $U_1 \subseteq U_2$.

Let $x \in U_1$. Then $x = 0$ or $x\neq 0$.

1. Assume $x = 0$, then $x \in U_2$ since $U_2$ is a subspace of $V$.
2. Assume $x \neq 0$.

   2.1) Then $x \notin W$ since $U_1 \cap W = \{0\}$ and $x \in U_1$ and $x \neq 0$.

   2.2) Then $x = x + 0 \in U_1 \oplus W$.

   2.3) Therefore $x + 0 \in U_2 \oplus W$.

   2.4) Therefore $x \in U_2$ since $x \notin W$.

   2.5) Therefore $U_1 \subseteq U_2$.

Case 2: Show $U_2 \subseteq U_1$. Same as Case 1, just interchange $U_2$ with $U_1$.

Therefore $U_1 = U_2$.

Comment: 2.4)  is wrong. You are confusing a  sum for a union.

Comment: Since you know the theorem is incorrect, you presumably know a counterexample. In which case, you can see which step(s) fail.

Comment: If the proof were correct you would not have proved that *subspaces have inverses for direct sums* but rather that *cancellability holds for direct sums of subspaces*, two rather different things.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think I understand what you mean. Should the title then be changed to "What's wrong with this proof that cancellability holds for direct sums of subspaces."

Comment: @ArnautB that'd be a much better title!

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Thanks. I see what you mean. Feed the counterexample in the above "proof" and see where it goes wrong. That is a lot like debugging a computer program. Is there a generic term for this?

Comment: @ArnautB: None that I am aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @geetha290krm for pointing out the flaw. To add to what he said in the comments:

$x + 0 \in U_2 \oplus W$ does not imply $x \in U_2$ and $0 \in W$, nor does it imply $0 \in U_2$ and $x \in W$, rather it means $x + 0$ is the sum of something from $U_2$ and something from $W$.

Edit 1: The flaw is in step 2.4).

Edit 2: I was assuming the following incorrect property of sum of subsets:

If $x \in U_2 + W$ and $x \notin W$ then $x \in U_2$.